# Issue translating method reference to SQL EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm facing a problem when trying to translate a method reference to SQL in a LINQ to SQL query. Here's a simplified code snippet to illustrate the issue:

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
    
    public string ProcessData()
    {
        // Data processing logic
        return (this.Property * 655).ToString();
    }
}
```

```cs
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

var query = dbContext.Entities
                     .Where(entity => entity.SomeCondition)
                     .Select(x => x.ProcessData()); // Method reference not translating to SQL

var result = query.ToList();
```

The entity class has a `ProcessData` method that performs data processing. The goal is to apply this method within the LINQ query, but EF fails to translate the method reference to SQL.

> The LINQ expression 'x => x.ProcessData()' could not be translated

I've found two potential solutions to work around this issue:

1. Switch to client evaluation: switching to client evaluation by materializing entities into memory first, and then applying the method reference on the client side. However, this approach loads all data into memory, which may be inefficient for large datasets.

```cs
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

var query = dbContext.Entities
                     .Where(entity => entity.SomeCondition)
                     .ToList() // execute the query
                     .Select(x => x.ProcessData());

var result = query.ToList();
```

2. Extracting the method logic and using it directly in the LINQ query. This avoids the method reference but may lead to code duplication and a loss of encapsulation.

```cs
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

var query = dbContext.Entities
                     .Where(entity => entity.SomeCondition)
                     .Select(ProcessData);

var result = query.ToList();

public string ProcessData(Entity entity)
{
    // Random logic
    return (entity.Property * 655).ToString();
}
```

I'm seeking insights on why EF 6 can translate the second solution but not the first one. Additionally, I'm open to suggestions on maintaining encapsulation without resorting to client evaluation.

Comment: For the record, if you're using Entity Framework then you're not using LINQ to SQL. LINQ to SQL is a specific LINQ provider that supports only SQL Server. If you're using EF, the LINQ provider you're using is LINQ to Entities.

Comment: As you suggest, an EF query has to be converted to SQL code by the LINQ to Entities provider. The database knows nothing about your `ProcessData` method so there's no SQL it can be converted to. You either have to do the work to make the database aware of that functionality or do it outside of that provider. One option would be to use your second option but with an extension method in a dedicated class.

Comment: If you look at the query generated by that second option, does it actually include the multiplication? I would expect not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the first example doesn't work while the second *can* work, so long as the function still conforms to being translated to SQL is that EF can translate expressions to SQL, but not the actual executtion of methods.

One option you can to keep your code encapsulated:

A static method in your entity method that can be called by a member method when dealing with entities, or served as an expression:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
    
    public string ProcessData()
    {
        return Entity.DoProcessData(this);
    }

    public static string DoProcessData(Entity entity)
    {
        return (entity.Property * 655).ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in your Linq query, similar to the second example, but encapsulated in your Entity:

```
var query = dbContext.Entities
    .Where(entity => entity.SomeCondition)
    .Select(Entity.DoProcessData);
```

I was looking at other options to expose an expression but it honestly was looking a lot messier. There is probably a cleaner way to expose the logic as an expression or Func that can be used within the `Select` clause. However keep in mind that whatever approach you use, the content of the conditions must be able to be translated down into SQL otherwise you will be left with needing to materialize the entity first.